# Multiline Text Fields Append Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, multiline-text-field, append-changes

Is it possible in Sharepoint online to create or modify a list view, that instead of showing "View Entries" in multiple-line text column with append-only checked, will show all entries for that element, so user will not have to click it and open every element, every time he needs to read comments?

I only want to use Jquery/javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a field customzer to the append-only field:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer

Then, retrieve data from the version history with pnp and display it in the view:

```
pnp.sp.web.getList(listUrl)
            .items
            .getById(id)
            .versions
            .get()
            .then(function(versions){
                // combine all versions into a string and render it
            });
```